# How to make a bot greet newcomers?

Tags: discord.js

I would like to make a bot that greets users that joined the server.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! This is too broad. Could you please share your code what have you tried so far and what was the result? Refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You mean if user join in server then send message welcome?

Comment: @BeamKunGzMARK, yes, and the message should contain his username...

Comment: And the bot is supposed to be a new bot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to listen for the **guildMemberAdd** event, which is when someone joins.

After that, you need to check if the server is **YOUR** server, get the channel, and send the welcome message.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    if (member.guild.id !== "YOUR-GUILD-ID") return;
    var channel = client.channels.cache.get('YOUR-CHANNEL-ID');
    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, <@!${member.id}>!`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const defaultChannel = guild.channels.find(channel => channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES"));
const userlist = newUsers.map(u => u.toString()).join(" ");
defaultChannel.send("Welcome our new users!\n" + userlist);
newUsers.clear();
```

this is a code sample

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome dm message [guildMemberAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.4.2/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) (Discord.js Version 11.4.2)

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member =>{
  await member.send(Embed);
});
```

Goodbye dm message [guildMemberRemove](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.4.2/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberRemove) (Discord.js Version 11.4.2)

```js
client.on('guildMemberRemove', async member =>{
  await member.send(Embed);
});
```